# ROOM OutOfMemoryError R(OOM)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-room, android-livedata

I am seeing these errors in my play-console. Does anybody know how to best deal with OOM Errors in room?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString (Native Method)
  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString (CursorWindow.java:451)
  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
  at org.walleth.data.transactions.TransactionDAO_Impl$8.compute (TransactionDAO_Impl.java:1272)
  at org.walleth.data.transactions.TransactionDAO_Impl$8.compute (TransactionDAO_Impl.java:1212)
  at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run (ComputableLiveData.java:87)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Unless that's a really huge `String`, Room might not be your problem, but merely where you're crashing. OOMs have two triggers: requesting too big of a memory block (think `Bitmap`) or genuinely being out of memory due to a leak somewhere. In the latter case, where you're crashing just happens to be where you finally ran out of memory, but is not necessarily where the leak is. Do you get a variant of this crash log that tells you how big of an allocation failed?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a variant of the crash-log where I see how big of an allocation failed. But it could be a huge string (the data-field might be big in some cases) - Is there any way I can catch this OOM and just ignore this item (will be contract deployment most likely and I am not interested in this there anyway)

Comment: You don't have a way to catch that particular exception very well, as it is occurring on a background thread that you are not in control of, and LiveData does not propagate exceptions. Consider not having your DAO return a LiveData, but instead use an RxJava type. Or, make this query synchronous in the DAO and arrange to call the @Query method on some background thread of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Will try to use the paging-lib first: https://github.com/walleth/walleth/issues/110 - maybe it is also the amount of transactions loaded - could be many in some cases.

Comment: Could this be solved by making the query as a Transaction?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction.html It's hard to know the exact cause from the log, but maybe you can try it out and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - why do you think a transaction would help here?

Comment: Giving it a second thought, it might not help with out of memory error since it will do the same operations but just being more consistent if the query is too large. It could only help you with data accuracy in case of an error during the query if you are updating anything. These are the most troublesome errors since it seems you can't even locate which query is the faulty one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you transferring huge data at once?

If it is a list you are filling, you can do it lazily and get it 100 by 100 for example.

Also If your response from database has many columns, `SELECT` the ones that you use.